# How do I toggle color attributes in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to toggle the color of a button every time it's clicked. I'm able change the color initially, but not able to change it back.

```
$("#greenCirc").click(function(){
    if($("#greenCirc").css("background-color", "green")){
        $("#greenCirc").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }   
    else{
        $("#greenCirc").css("background-color", "green");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.css("background-color")` - with *one* parameter - to retrieve the current color value. But, note that this will give you an RGB string like `rgb(0, 128, 0)` instead of `green`. Compare against that:

```js
$("#greenCirc").click(function() {
  if ($("#greenCirc").css("background-color") === "rgb(0, 128, 0)") {
    $("#greenCirc").css("background-color", "yellow");
  } else {
    $("#greenCirc").css("background-color", "green");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greenCirc">click</div>
```

But I would much prefer using a class instead:

```js
$("#greenCirc").click(function() {
  this.classList.toggle('on');
});
```

```css
#greenCirc {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#greenCirc.on {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greenCirc">click</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this way easier with jQuery `toggleClass`

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "toggled" );
});
```

```css
button {
  background: green;
}

button.toggled {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
```